# Execution python script in terminal or pvpython in mac

Tags: python-2.7, paraview

I installed ParaView 5.7 and record a python script with it.
In Windows 10, I'm able to open a pvpython shell and execute code but in my Mac I can't find this pvpython shell.

I have tried executing the script in the terminal `python my_script.py` and get the error

```
from paraview.simple import *
ImportError: No module named paraview.simple
```

My `sys.path` is

```
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.3.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/Users/jane/Desktop', 
'/home/jane/Code/Kitware/build/VTK/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', 
'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC'
]
```

What else should I add to the `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Mac, `pvpython` is installed in `/Applications/ParaView-5.7.0.app/Contents/bin/pvpython`

Answer (score 0):

Installed paraview using conda

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge paraview
```

This works for me